# AngularJs ngRepeat not updating on change to variable

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:$parent.limit=($parent.limit||5)">
    ...
    <a ng-if="$last" ng-bind="$parent.limit===Infinity ? 'Read Less':'Read More'" ng-click="$parent.limit=$parent.limit===Infinity?5:Infinity"></a>
</div>
```

So the initial limit is only 5 items, and clicking the link changes the text between Read more/Read less. But ngRepeat doesn't pick up on the change and add/remove items. I want ngRepeat to update when I change `$parent.limit` variable. I'd like to avoid using the controller, if possible.

Comment: Using $parent is a huge code smell. Call methods of your scope instead, and put the logic there. ng-repeat and ng-if both define their own scope.

Comment: @JBNizet This will be my plan B. I have a lot of ng-repeats to update in our app, and it'd be nice to avoid using the controller for such a simple task. Mainly because my work and colleagues are adamant about unit testing everything, and copying and pasting the same thing everywhere, just to change the variable name is about as exciting as watching paint dry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng-repeat` directive I believe creates another scope under it for it's child items. So then you would **not** be talking to the same parent that's referred to in the `<div>` element. So in your `<a>` tag you may need to talk to the parent's parent scope.

So try `$parent.$parent` instead of just `$parent` within your anchor tag inside of your `ng-repeat`.

Of course doing this will make the AngularJS gods shed a tear, so I recommend creating a controller *or* calling a method in your `ng-click` that will propagate up to the current controller for his template. Then you can move all of that logic outside of your template.

Comment: Well the AngularJS gods win today. Too bad they don't come down from their heavens and help do the extra work with me. $parent.$parent doesn't update, but using a controller does.